# Change record automatically

Tags: php, mysql

On the website i'm developing i'm making a system for ban and unban users.

In my database i have a table 'banned' with fields about the bans (userID, active, date was made, reason ecc).

What i want to do is:

Add another field for expire date, and when this date occur, change automatically the field 'active' to 0.

How i can do that?

Comment: what are your thoughts on this? what should be done? Please share your  thoughts so that SO can help you..

Comment: If it's already expired, then there's no need to mark it as inactive.  To do this though, you'd either have to periodically do it in your web page code or do it with a cron task.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would not use two fields like you did -- because I would not want to depend on a task to change back the `active` field when the un-ban date is reached.

Instead, I would only use one datetime field, called like `banned_until`; and this field would either:

- Be `NULL` when the user is not banned,
- Or contain the date until which the user is banned.

Then, when the user tries to do something *(log-in, post, ...)*, I would check that :

- This field is `NULL`, in which case the user is not banned
- Or that the date contained in this field is in the past, in which can the user has been banned, but is no longer.

In the second case, you could even reset the field to `NULL`, as the un-ban date has been reached.

Comment: I had already thought of this solution, but i use two field to keep track of all the bans. So if the same user do something against rules, i can watch all infos. If i need to ban again the same user i will ad another record to the table with new expire date ecc.  And the function for unban users need to be automated, because when a user is banned his profile page will not be displayed.. and if the user do not login, the ban will stay active after the expire date..

Comment: In this case, I'd say you just have to check that no active ban *(i.e. no ban that ends in the future)* is present in your table -- no need to "unban" the user, you just have to test that no ban is still not-finished.

Comment: Ok i catched what are you saying.. On login, or user pages etc.. instead of check if ban is active, i check if there are ban that end in future.. right?

Comment: Exactly :-) Afterall, a ban that has not "expired" yet is an active ban.

Answer (score 2):

Its either you use a cron script or when getting banned users, you apply a where clause to check if the the ban has expired

Answer (score 0):

Create a php script that will check if time is passed the expiration date. SQL will be something like this:

```
UPDATE banned SET active=0 WHERE expire_date<=NOW()
```

Save it as a for example `task.php`

Then create a cron task with `crontab -e`

```
*/10 * * * * php /path/to/your/taks/task.php
```

And this will cause this script to be executed every 10min and unban all banned ppl.

--

There are other ways, perhaps better ones, like e.g. Pascal described, but this answer is for your idea.

Answer (score 0):

You can compare `expiry_date` value with `current_date` to check if a user is active or not on his login.

```
SELECT 
 ( DATE_FORMAT( expiry_date_field, '%Y-%m-%d' )
   < 
   DATE_FORMAT( CURRENT_DATE, '%Y-%m-%d' )
 ) AS isActive
FROM
 banned 
WHERE
 user_id=?;
```

A `0` returned represents *in-active* status and `1` as *active*.

But irrespective of a user's login, if you want to maintain active status of users, you can achieve this [***using the Event Scheduler***](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/events.html).

Following example gives you an idea in implementing one.

```
drop event if exists event_user_bans_scheduling;
delimiter //

create event if not exists event_user_bans_scheduling
--  on schedule every 86400 second starts 00:00:00
--  at timestamp( adddate( current_date, 1 ),'00:00:00' )
  on schedule every 1 day starts timestamp( current_date + 1, '00:00:01' )

  comment 'Scheduler to update active status of users'
  do
    UPDATE my_app_db.banned
      SET ACTIVE=0
      WHERE
        date_format( expiry_date_field,'%Y-%m-%d' ) = date_format( CURRENT_DATE, '%Y-%m-%d' );
;
//
delimiter ;
```

***Note***:
The global `event_scheduler` system variable determines whether the Event Scheduler is enabled and running on the server. Read complete notes on [*`Event Scheduler Configuration`*](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/events-configuration.html) before working on MySQL events.